# Import image as a image resources in Lotus notes

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus

How can I get the attachment(Image) from notesdocument and then import the image to Image resource as a design element into nsf through lotus script & Java?

Answer (score 2):

To import image resources in Notes database via code you basically need to convert the image resource into Base64 encoding, create a DXL file with this Base 64 code and then import the DXL in database. Below are some example where this has been done.

1. [Upload Image Resources from The Web](http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/EPSD-54VLYL)
2. [Using LotusScript to import an image resource](http://markwambler.blogspot.com/2006/05/using-lotusscript-to-import-image.html)
3. [Import image resources via LotusScript & Java](http://naveegator.blogspot.com/2011/12/import-image-resources-via-lotusscript.html)

Answer (score 0):

The alternate approach is to switch on webDAV (build in for design elements) and simply HTTP Post the image data to the NSF